# Sum and product of rational numbers is unity

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, rational-numbers

Consider the system of  equations:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = 1$$

$$\prod_{i=1}^n X_i = 1$$

It is reasonably simple to show that for $n\ge 4$, this system admits a rational solution $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{Q}^n$.

It suffices to find a solution for $n=4,5,6,7$ and for all larger values of $n$ solutions can be obtained by appending $(-1,-1,1,1)$ to a solution for $n-4$.

For $n=2$, there are no rational solutions. I'm pretty certain the existence of rational solutions for $n=3$ is an open problem, but I cannot find any discussion of it, largely because its hard to search for.

Is this a named problem? A solved problem? Can anyone direct me to any work that has been done on it?

Comment: In your notation, can $x_i$ be a rational number that can be written as $\frac{a}{b}$, where $a,b \in \mathbb Z$

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by "find a solution for $n=4,5,6,7$ and everything else can be obtained by adding and subtracting $1$".

Comment: A [reference](http://www.theproblemsite.com/ask/2016/03/the-sum-of-three-numbers-is-equal-to-the)

Comment: [Another one](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/11/30/tangent-identity/) connecting it interestingly to $\tan(a)\tan(b)\tan(c)=\tan(a)+\tan(b)+\tan(c)$

Comment: @Kevin What is meant by $x_i$?

Comment: A rewording for anyone still confused by the problem, the OP asks to find $x,y,z\in \Bbb Q$ such that $x+y+z=x\cdot y\cdot z = 1$.  The op states that had there been four variables or more, that it is possible, but does not know whether or not it is possible for the three variable case.

Comment: I cannot see a solution for $n=5$

Comment: @SimpleArt for $n=5$ it is perhaps the easiest one.  $1+1+1-1-1=(1)(1)(1)(-1)(-1)=1$.  It is $n=4$ that I do not personally see immediately.

Comment: For $n=4$, $\frac{3}{2} -\frac{3}{2} + \frac{4}{3} - \frac{1}{3} = (\frac{3}{2})(\frac{-3}{2})(\frac{4}{3})(\frac{-1}{3}) = 1$. Clarifying comments much appreciated.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ah, yes, my bad.  And I much agree.

Comment: @Kevin How to solve a more general solution, that finds all solutions satisfying $n\ge4$

Answer (score 3):

For $n=3$, taking $x_3 = 1 - x_1 - x_2$ we get
$-1 + x_1 x_2  - x_1 x_2^2 - x_1^2 x_2 = 0$.  This is an elliptic curve with Weierstrass form $s^3+(23/48)s-181/864+t^2$, according to Maple.  I think it ought to be a finite computation (not one that I know how to do) to find generators for the  rational points.

EDIT: Well, apparently this is an unsolved problem in general.  But unless I've made a mistake, Sage tells me the only rational points in the Weierstrass form are $(s,t) = (-1/12, \pm 1/2)$, which correspond to points at $\infty$ in the $x_1,x_2$ form), so there are no rational solutions in the case $n=3$.

```
sage:  E = EllipticCurve([23/48,181/864])
sage:  E.torsion_subgroup()
 Torsion Subgroup isomorphic to Z/3 associated to the Elliptic Curve
 defined by y^2 = x^3 + 23/48*x + 181/864 over Rational Field
sage:  E.torsion_subgroup().gens()
 ((1/12 : 1/2 : 1),)
sage:  E.rank()
  0
```

EDIT: For $n=4$, taking $x_4 = 1 - x_1 - x_2 - x_3$ and $x_3 = 3/2$, the elliptic curve for $x_1$ and $x_2$ has rank $1$.  Thus there are infinitely many rational solutions for $n=4$ with $x_3 = 3/2$, including
$ \left[-\frac13,\frac43,\frac32,-\frac32\right]$ and 
$ \left[-\frac{289}{210}, \frac{150}{119}, \frac{3}{2}, -\frac{98}{255}\right]$.

I'd appreciate confirmation from elliptic curve experts that I'm using Sage correctly.